# CE Image - Only generating half the images?

Tags: php, ce-image, apache

I've recently moved an EE site to a new server (a reasonably beefy VPS from Memset), after lots of hunting around changing paths, I've the site working with only one problem.  CE Image is used on the site heavily, and it seems to be only creating around half the thumbnails per page.

The problem pages are listing pages, so 24 entries per page, each entry has a small thumb created, and a larger (hover) thumb created.  On the new server only half of them are being created (interestingly always the thumb + the hover)

I've checked the originals exist (they do!)
If I reduce from 24 per page to 12 per page, it seems to create 8 of the 12 pairs
Template Debugging is showing no errors.

So I'm a little stumped.. this code works perfectly on the other server, so I'm thinking possibly an Apache / PHP set up issue (more ram? Threads? Workers needed?)

If I inspect the generated code, the HTML looks fine and dandy, with all the file names looking as they should but only half of the images actually exist.

Template code snippet below

```
<li>
    <a href="/image/{url_title}" title="{title}" class="thumb" data-large="{exp:ce_img:pair src="/originals/if{entry_id}.jpg" max="400" filename="hover-{url_title}" cache="yes" refresh="360"}{made}{/exp:ce_img:pair}">
        {exp:ce_img:pair src="/originals/if{entry_id}.jpg" max="110" cache="yes" refresh="360"}<img src="{made}" alt="{title}" />{/exp:ce_img:pair}
    </a>
    <abbr title="{title}">#{entry_id} / /originals/if{entry_id}.jpg <!-- This shows the correct image path / entry ID etc --> </abbr>
    <a href="/image/{url_title}" title="{title}">view</a> | <a href="#{entry_id}" class="add" rel="{entry_id}">add to lightbox</a>
</li>
```

Some versions and server info

```
PHP 5.4.11 (128MB memory limit)
MySQL 5.1.66
Apache 2.2.16 (Debian)
ExpressionEngine 2.4.0
CE Image 2.4.1
Server is a VPS, 2 Cores, 2Gb ram etc.
```

Any help / ideas / pointers greatly appreciated!  Thanks :-)

Geoff

Edit

A sample of the template debug out put (Basically 24 times the following, with names replaced of course!)

```
(0.162424 / 10.88MB)        ***  CE Image debug: Base path: '/srv/www/redacted.com/public_html/'
(0.162442 / 10.88MB)        ***  CE Image debug: Source image: '/originals/if133979.jpg', Fallback image: ''
(0.162451 / 10.88MB)        ***  CE Image debug: The image '/srv/www/redacted.com/public_html/images/made/originals/hover-file_name_300_400.jpg' is not cached.
(0.162459 / 10.88MB)        ***  CE Image debug: Image opened '/srv/www/redacted.com/public_html/originals/if133979.jpg'.
(0.162466 / 10.88MB)        ***  CE Image debug: Image saved to /srv/www/redacted.com/public_html/images/made/originals/hover-file_name_300_400.jpg.
(0.162998 / 10.24MB)       -> Data Returned
```

Comment: Hi Geoff! Do you get any useful messages from the template debugger? Take a look at [Debugging](http://www.causingeffect.com/software/expressionengine/ce-image/user-guide/troubleshooting#debugging) for more details on how to check your debug messages.

Comment: Nothing useful I can see.. I've edited the original post to add some examples.

Comment: This is a weird longshot, but I wonder if the fact that your image paths are prefixed with `if` is throwing the template parser for a loop, somehow interpreting that as the beginning of an "if" statement some of the time?

Comment: Good thinking, but afraid not.  A quick test of changing the names makes no difference.. also this was working fine on previous server.  G

Comment: So the template debugger tells you that all 24 images are being created and/or found, but when you look on the server (in **/images/made/originals/**), some are not there? Just trying to clarify what you mean by "actually exist". (Not showing when you expect them to in the browser, or they actually do not exist on the server?)

Comment: Were the half you're seeing generated while the site was on the other server? Any chance the half you're not seeing have been generated while on the current server?

Answer (score 3):

Thank you all for the help.

After a lot of digging around, once again the culprit was everyone's friend htaccess.  There was a rogue rule that included /images/ which seems to occasionally interfere, removing the rule, clearing the /made folder, clearing the EE tag cache and we are back in business.

Phew...

Lesson learnt, if in doubt it's always blooming .htaccess :-)

Answer (score 0):

I'd first delete all "cache" created files for CE Image so you are starting with all newly created images. Then rerun the page.

Also, clear browser cache and force a hard page load.

Check PHP error logs to see if there are any memory errors. Might also just increase PHP memory for kicks.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem recently with CE Image and a server move. The fix was to put the path to the HTML document root in EE's config.php file like so:

```
$config['ce_image_document_root'] = '/path/to/html';
```

I hope this works for you as it did for me.